# Where can I get nutrition information about food?

Tags: protein, food, carbohydrate, vitamins, fiber

I am plannign on making an app that uses nutritional information about food, but finding good and reliable sources in the Internet for it is proving to be a challenge.

Every website displays different values of proteins, fibers, vitamins and minerals for the same fruits (for example or bananas) and the one website I though I could use (FDA) does not have such information.

I am looking for a reliable source which contains this kind of information for raw fruits and vegetables, but I have no idea where to start.

Does anyone here know a good reliable gov source or independent source that can provide this information for me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about data source recommendations for application development, and only loosely related to physical fitness.

Comment: How is this off-topic if I have seen similar question in here? Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question, as worded, is off-topic.  But, since I've written such a program in the past, I'll point you to what I used.  The USDA maintains a [Nurtient Database](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=8964) that can be downloaded.  If memory serves me, it's large and is distributed in several parts.  There is documentation to help you decipher each part of the download.